# NodeJs performance problem

Tags: performance, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I'm building a realtime stats application using NodeJs. For the prototype I'm using a Quad-Core AMD Opteron in a RackSpace server for the test with a nodejs server using the Cluster NodeJs ( http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/ ) and the MongoDb using the native nodejs driver.

Basically I've inserted a JS code in my company project that delivers content for a bunch of client's websites. This code "pings" my server each 10seconds calling for a image and passing parameters that I get in the server-side and insert ( or update ) in a MongoDb collection. In a "slow" time of the day I get about 3000 connections ( I get these using the netstat -natp command on terminal) each time that makes my cluster use about 25% of each core ( I get these using the "top" command ). But in a "busy" hour I get about 7000+ connections each time what makes my cluster go crazy ( about 80%+ use of each core ), and it seems that as the time goes by, the node degrades.
Is this normal? Or should Nodejs handle these hits in a more "easy" way? If I use Mongoose, the performance can increase?

In case you are curious about the MongoDb it uses about 4% of one core, which is fine by me ( without putting a index the use was about 50%+ but, at least, the index solved this performance problem ).

Thanks a lot for the patience,
Cheers.

Edit:

The code that makes the insert looks like this:
    db.open(function(err, db) { });

```
return connect.router(function(app){
    app.get("/pingserver/:clientid/:event/:cachecontrol", function(req, res, next){
    event:'+req.params.event + ', cachecontrol:' + req.params.cachecontrol);
        var timestamp = new Date(); 
          switch(req.params.event) {
          case 'load':
              var params = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

              db.collection('clientsessions', function(err, collection)         {
                try {

                    var client = {
                        id: req.params.clientid,
                        state: req.params.event + 'ed',
                        loadTime: timestamp.getTime(),
                        lastEvent: req.params.event,
                        lastEventTime: timestamp.getTime(),
                        lastEventDate: timestamp.toString(),
                        events: [{
                            event: req.params.event,
                            timestamp: timestamp.getTime(),
                            date: timestamp.toString()
                        }],
                        media: {
                            id: params.media.split('|')[0] || null,
                            title: unescape(params.media.split('|')[1]) || null
                        },
                        project: {
                            id: params.project.split('|')[0] || null,
                            name: unescape(params.project.split('|')[1]) || null
                        },
                        origin: req.headers['referer'] || req.headers['referrer'] || '',
                        userAgent: req.headers['user-agent'] || null,
                        userIp: req.socket && (req.socket.remoteAddress || (req.socket.socket && req.socket.socket.remoteAddress)),
                        returningUser: false
                    };
                }catch(e) {console.log(e);}       
                 collection.insert(client, function(err, doc) {
                 });
              });
              break;

          case 'ping':
              db.collection('clientsessions', function(err, collection) {
                  collection.update({id: req.params.clientid}, { 
                                                     $set : { lastEvent: req.params.event 
                                                             ,lastEventTime: timestamp.getTime(),lastEventDate: timestamp.toString()}
                                                   }, {}, function(err, doc) {});
              });
              break;

          default:
              db.collection('clientsessions', function(err, collection) {
                  collection.update({id: req.params.clientid}, { 
                                                     $set : {state: req.params.event+'ed'
                                                            , lastEvent: req.params.event 
                                                            , lastEventTime: timestamp.getTime()}
                                                   , $push : { events : { event: req.params.event, timestamp: timestamp.getTime(), date: timestamp.toString() } } }, {}, function(err, doc) {});
              });

              break;
          }

          if (!transparent) {
              console.log('!transparent');
              transparent = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../../public/images/transparent.gif', 'binary');
          }
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/gif');
          res.setHeader('Content-Length', transparent.length);

          res.end(transparent, 'binary');
      });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is this normal?

Depends, are connections going away on their own? Do they just keep building? Are you talking about "web connection" (http) or MongoDB connection?

What do the `mongod` logs say? What do the `node` logs say?

How many requests are you getting per second?

> Or should Nodejs handle these hits in a more "easy" way?

Hard to say without knowing what the code is doing.

How many simultaneous connections do you expect the box to handle?

> If I use Mongoose, the performance can increase?

So Mongoose is actually an object wrapper around `node-mongodb-native` driver. It is not a different driver, it's just a wrapper.

The wrapper going to add code to the code you already have. If you have a code problem, then adding code is not guaranteed to make the problem better. If mongoose does solve your problem, then it's doing something with connections that you're not. If that the case, you don't necessarily need Mongoose, you just need better connection management.

---

Look there are lots of potential sources for you issue.

The only way to get this solved is to break out the pieces and dig in with much more detail. Places to start:
 - are connections to MongoDB closing correctly (look at the db logs)?
 - do the logs contain any other errors?
 - do the same thing for the node logs?
 - do you have graphs regarding the memory usage? who's taking up the most memory?
 - when you get to 80% of each core, which process is doing this? `mongod`? `node`? something else?

To really help you out here, we need a lot more data about what's going on with the system.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to dig into this and post here. Just a note: As the nodeJS server starts I open the connection to the Mongo and I never close this. Is this ok? Or should I open the connection in each "ping" and close it after the update/insert ?

Comment: I think that you'll have to test both ways. The only example I've seen does this just once as you're doing it. You'll have to test the other method to see if it works correctly. As of this writing, `node-mongodb-native` does not have connection pooling. You just have that one open connection. I do not know how this interacts with Cluster.

Comment: Maybe this open connection is tapering the whole think? Well.. I have a presentation tomorrow so I can leave like that. Afterwards I'll try to use the Mongoose e see the logs. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Another alternative is drop the Node Cluster and try using a Nginx in the top of that. Has anyone made this?

Answer (score 1):

Continuous requests can be quite expensive especially if the timeout between them is small. In your case you are accepting between ~300-700+ concurrent requests per second and your system load can depend namely on what are you processing. You can try to switch to Mongoose, however I would rather look at the image handling and caching if it is applicable for your scenario, since DB seems not to be your bottleneck (although DB driver may also be the issue).

Comment: About the concurrent request they are between 3000 to 7000 ( or more ). When I arrived today at work I saw that the server dropped. It consumed almost all of the system memory and I had to restart it. Anyway I´ll try the Mongoose, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Just a quick question: Basically I receive the "ping" and store the data on the MongoDb. Do I have to close the connection after that? Also I'm opening the connection to the MongoDb at the server's start and don't close it never. Would open connection and close after the insert, increase performance?

Comment: Connection management should be handled by [connection pools](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Notes+on+Pooling+for+Mongo+Drivers) within [drivers](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoose-orm/browse_thread/thread/2f02d3a1f578836c). Try to use mongoose (if it's not a problem) which is using single non-blocking connection for all requests and see if the situation changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!transparent) {
          console.log('!transparent');
          transparent = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../../public/images/transparent.gif', 'binary');
      }
```

How often is transparent false? I don't see it defined in the code. You're blocking the entire Node process on synchronous disk IO, potentially for every request. Why? If you have to read the file from disk, do it asynchronously. If the file is static and small, maybe you should load it into memory once.

Comment: In one of my refactorings, I saw that and fixed it. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Node's `http` server has keep-alive by default. It causes too many useless connections in your case. Just try adding a header to `disable Keep-Alive` — a plain node with cluster would be fine.

```
res.setHeader("Connection", "close")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update:

I've dropped the cluster and put a Nginx layer on the server. So it took a lot longer to "degrade" but it is still doing that, especially consuming a lot of the system ram memory.
Any thoughts?

And thanks a lot for all the answers!

Edit:
Re-did some tests. I think that the MAIN PROBLEM is concerning the open connections. When I run a netstat on the Nginx port it says like 2000 connections. When I run on each nodejs app port it says 2000 ( or more ). Basically my "best case scenario" would be that the sum of the open connections on the nodejs apps would match the open connections on the Nginx port, right? I think that this is the main problem and it's affecting the huge "time_wait" statuses.

Comment: Basically I'm having A LOT of TIME_WAIT connections.

Comment: About 21k TIME_WAIT connections. I'm guessing that this is consuming the ram memory and degrading the server.

Answer (score 0):

You might also just wanna serve up that transparent gif from a buffer as done here:

https://gist.github.com/657246#comments

Comment: Actually I did a whole different approach. But thanks for the help!